# using instance initializer to deal with constructor overloading

Tags: java

A pattern I sometimes see is that a constructor might take either no argument or one argument. Now, I wonder whether the 'better' approach is to move common code to the most defined constructor - or to use the *instance initializer* in this case. For example, one way of always generating an ID for every class created:

```
 public SomeClass(){
     this("Hello");
 }

 public SomeClass(String s){
     this.s = s;
     this.id = generateId();
 }
```

versus writing it like this:

```
 {
     this.id = generateId(); // method does not depend on the class
 }

 public SomeClass(){
      this("Hello");
 }

 public SomeClass(String s){
      this.s = s;
 }
```

The reason for using the Instance Initializer would be because I want to always run the method when the class is created, and in the future someone else might change the class's constructors and forget to do this. Whilst it is less likely to remove the instance initializer (without realizing what you are doing).

But on the other hand, I am not sure how about readability in this case.

*The examples are a bit contrived, not real-world examples.*

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good idea to me. I'd rely on code review to catch "adding a constructor without chaining to the master one" and end up with more readable code. Note that in real life situations you're likely to have to chain to the master constructor for other parameters anyway. The instance initializer can *only* help with state that doesn't rely on constructor parameters.

Comment: @JonSkeet fair point for when they can be chained. What about parameter overloading? When you have one constructor which takes an `integer` and another one taking a `String` or something. (For whatever reason. In this case, would we end up duplicating? (Of course, I suppose you could use a Builder at this point and take care of it there)

Comment: In almost all cases, I'd end up with a "master" constructor that everything else chains to. It's very rare for me to find a situation that doesn't cover. An instance initializer would be reasonable for that case, but it would be a rarity.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! I have not encountered a situation like this myself, but was just curious about a potential usecase :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason for using the Instance Initializer would be because I want
>   to always run the method when the class is created, and in the future
>   someone else might change the class's constructors and forget to do
>   this. Whilst it is less likely to remove the intance initializer
>   (without realising what you are doing).

Doing the one (using the Instance Initializer) or the other one (constructor) should not be used as trick to avoid coding error when the class is modified.
And anyway, why Initializer would give better insurance about it ?

You want to ensure that the constructor do what it designed to do ?
Writing an unit test that validates this behavior and that is automatically executed at each build.
That's all.

Comment: True, unit tests should catch that.
What about code duplication? This is kind of a separate question I suppose. But what if you have 2 constructors, one taking `Object A` and the other `Object B`. Now you'd have code in both constructors to generate the ID. (Duplicate code). The instance initializer could avoid duplicate code in this case.

Comment: You can always introduce a common constructor (with private modifier if it makes sense) that does this common processing and that is called by two other constructors (constructor chaining)

Comment: 200 % correct ... and thanks for leaving some space for another answer ;-)

Comment: I left this space at 175% for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reasonable solution here:

```
 private final Whatever id = generateId();
```

In other words:

- make sure the compiler *knows* that this should be initialized (so use *final*)
- and instead of using an init block (rather uncommon) simply do initialize once, "in place"

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a use of instnace initializer in real life. (I actually did see it and played with it for a bit in one of theoretical questions on this site). In real life though you often can see a static initializer block:

```
public class Bla {
  static {
     //do something
  }
  ....
}
```

As for common code what could be done is to have a method called `init()` that is called by all constructors. In your example it would look like

```
 public SomeClass(){
      this("Hello");
 }

 public SomeClass(String s){
      init();
      this.s = s;
 }

  private init()  {
     this.id = generateId(); // method does not depend on the class
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what my first thought would be too. But then if you have an init call in multiple constructors, you still have code duplictation. ^^ (See the comment in the question above)

Comment: not really. If your init method has several operations and then you call this method from several constructors it is exactly the way to avoid the code duplication. Trying to avoid a single method call duplication is a bit extreme (IMHO).